# Solving the system with $\tan x+\tan y=1-\tan x\tan y$ and $ \sin2y-\sqrt 2 \sin x=1$

Tags: trigonometry

I have came across this system of trigonometry equations.

$$\tan x + \tan y=1-\tan x\tan y$$
$$ \sin2y-\sqrt 2 \sin x=1$$

I have tried with expressing $\tan$ as $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and using the formula for $\sin2\alpha$. But I haven't gone any further than the start.

Comment: have a look at the addition formula for $\tan$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The first equation can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\tan(x) + \tan(y) = 1 - \tan(x)\tan(y) & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(y)} = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \tan(x+y) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x + y = \frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi
\end{align*}
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Substituting such relation into the second equation, one has that
\begin{align*}
\sin(2y) - \sqrt{2}\sin(x) = 1 & \Longleftrightarrow \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2x\right) - \sqrt{2}\sin(x) = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \cos(2x) - \sqrt{2}\sin(x) = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 1 - 2\sin^{2}(x) - \sqrt{2}\sin(x) = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sin(x)(\sqrt{2}\sin(x) + 1) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

Notice that $\tan(x)\tan(y) = 1$ iff
\begin{align*}
\tan(x)\tan(y) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\sin(x)\sin(y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)\\\\
\cos(x)\cos(y) \neq 0
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\cos(x+y) \neq 0\\\\
\cos(x)\cos(y) \neq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle x + y \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + m\pi\\\\
\displaystyle x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\\\\
\displaystyle y \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + p\pi
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $m,n,p\in\mathbb{Z}$. As it can be checked, the proposed solutions satisfy such restrictions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i have tried the first step you did, but i quickly realized i have no proof that 1−tan(x)tan(y) is not equal to 0.

Comment: You are right. I am going to improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the additional proof.

Comment: No worries, I am glad to help!

Comment: Shorter argument for the edited portion. If $1-\tan(x)\tan(y)=0$, then by the given relation, $\tan(x)+\tan(y)=0$, and $\tan(y)=-\tan(x)$. So $1+\tan^2(x)=0$, which is not possible.

Comment: @alex.jordan thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it.